# Is it possible to use class objects as variables in class definition?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I want to do something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Instance {

public:
    const string ClassName = "Instance";
    string Name = ClassName;
    bool Archivable = true;
    Instance Parent;
    
};

int main() {
    
    Instance obj1;
    Instance obj2;
    
    obj2.Parent = obj1; // set the parent instance to obj1
    obj2.Parent.Name = "NewName"; // change the parent’s (obj1) name   to “NewName”
    
    cout << obj1.Name; // I want “NewName” to be printed out.
    
}
```

The problem is that I get an error, and I don’t know how to store objects as references.

Comment: The simple solution is to make `Parent` a pointer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I assume OP comes from a language where all class instances behave as references. Then the question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not storing a reference but a value, so basically it is going to copy the value of `obj1` into `obj2.Parent`. So when you change `obj2.Parent`'s value you update the nested object which is not a reference to the true parent.

You have a few ways to manage ownership of nested elements which all depends on the context.

You could store a pointer:

```
Instance *Parent;
```

You could store a reference, which is almost the same thing, but quite uncommon in my experience:

```
Instance &Parent;
```

The easiest and best way would be to store a smart_pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<Instance> Parent;
```

Edit, a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Instance {

public:
    const string ClassName = "Instance";
    string Name = ClassName;
    bool Archivable = true;
    Instance *Parent;
    
};

int main() {
    
    Instance obj1;
    Instance obj2;
    
    obj2.Parent = &obj1; // set the parent instance to obj1
    obj2.Parent->Name = "NewName"; // change the parent’s (obj1) name   to “NewName”
    
    cout << obj1.Name << endl; // I want “NewName” to be printed out.       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would I clear the parent though? I did obj2.Parent = NULL; But “NewName” prints instead of “Instance”. Is it also possible to “lock” the property so that it can’t be changed anymore?

Comment: What do you mean clear? Both obj1 and obj2 are on the stack, so you can't delete them. But you could do something like obj2.Parent = nullptr;

Comment: I'd be cautious about recommending a `std::unique_ptr` as the "best" way. It might be, but from the description we don't know the intended ownership semantics of the `Instance` class. Is it supposed to be possible for multiple children to share the same parent?